# How does it form a conditional event which will happen in the future?

Tags: gramática, condicional, futuro

Talking about a conditional event which will happen in the future. But here, future form isn't used. Which of the below sentences is grammatically correct?

> Whenever these bills have been paid, call me.
>
> Whenever these bills are paid, call me.

> Cuando estas facturas están pagadas, llámame.

or

> Cuando estas facturas se pagan, llámame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of them is correct. For this construction you need the [subjunctive in its present form](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modo_subjuntivo#Presente):

> Cuando estas facturas **estén** pagadas, llámame.
>
> Cuando estas facturas se **paguen**, llámame.

Comment: You're right, its my mistake. It should be `paguen`. But why `estén` and not `están`?

Comment: It's exactly the same construction, present of subjunctive, so you have to use it in the verb "[estar](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=elbYf00qvVcRjg2FXzjo)".